# Show partial JPA queries with aggregate functions ( sum, groupby )

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

I'm trying to perform a SQL query using safe CriteriaQuery in JPA 2 and I would like to show the results in a JSF page using a datatable.
For the view layer I'm using PrimeFaces and the JPA implementation is EclipseLink.

I would like to display a query such as:

```
select ges_venta_lineas.producto_id, sum (ges_venta_lineas.IMPORTETOTAL) from ges_venta_lineas group by ges_venta_lineas.producto_id
```

that using CriteriaQuery look like this.

```
public List <VentaLinea> getResumen () {
        CriteriaBuilder em.getCriteriaBuilder qb = ();
        CriteriaQuery <VentaLinea> c = qb.createQuery (VentaLinea.class);
        Root <VentaLinea> root = C.From (VentaLinea.class);

        Expression <BigDecimal> sum = qb.sum (root.get (VentaLinea_.importeTotal));
        c.multiselect (root.get (VentaLinea_.producto), sum);
        c.groupBy (root.get (VentaLinea_.producto));
        Query query = getEntityManager () createQuery (c).;
        query.getResultList return ();
    }
```

I am getting some errors because by using the function sum, a new column that does not correspond to any field of VentaLinea class so I understand that this method should not return List , I guess it will be a simple way to do it, because what I'm trying to do is not a big deal, a possible solution would be to use classes to "encapsulate" the outcome of the querys and to return a list of that kind, but I think is too much unnecessary to create a class for each possible query that i need.
I hope someone can help me, sorry for possible grammar mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to get out of your query is not a list of entities, but a list of tuples. It is not possible to use `List<VentaLinea>` as a result.

JPA provides 2 standard ways to handle this situation:

- return untyped `List<?>` or [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Tuple.html), which will effectively hold both VentaLinea entity and the result of `sum`, either as `Object[]` or as [Tuple](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Tuple.html)
- create a wrapper class around both values, which are passed to it via constructor, and then you might build a query to return list of that class

More details on how to implement it here:  http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select#Multi_Selection_

Comment: Yes i solved it returning a List of Object[], Thnk you very much for your answer

Comment: @OnrdejM: isn't is possible somehow to use the constructor method to write the aggregated value into the original entity? I.e. for the above example, create a `public VentaLinea(VentaLinea other, Long sum)` copy constructor?

Comment: @Arthur, that approach is possible, but would most probably not work as you would expect. Such approach would create plain Java objects, in no way connected to the database, unless you would call em.merge() on it. It would be confusing to create instances of an entity class, which are not real entities. I would prefer to create a separate class to make the code clearer to avoid future mistakes based on false assumptions.

Comment: @OndrejM: thanks, I understand that it will be a detached entity, but for simple reporting purposes this might be enough. I'm also trying to find the best way to store a calculated field for JSP display without creating a class just for this. Tried `@Formula` but it was buggy. So now I use a `@Transient` field named `sum` on the entity, issue `select s, sum(rows)`, walk through the result list and use Object[0].setSum(Object[1]). I don't like the extra step though.

Comment: Yes, using an entity class to create plain objects via constructor works and might be enough. I just don't recommend it as it might be confusing. It is not so much work to introduce a new class just for a JSP - the code is cleaner and you can create a public static class nested into the entity class, if you don't want to create a new file for it.